# one login for jenkins and auto login to SVN url in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins job and I restricted access to user only to build an read.
When we create a job we will give login credentials to SVN and dependency path URL's like Nexus etc. When I create a job I will remove all the credentials of mine as admin and leave it blank. When the user try to build it fails as there is no login credentials for SVN, Nexus, and he cannot configure as we made it like a template.

Is there any possibility without configuring the template that with his logid to Jenkins, when he build the job that it takes his login credentials of Jenkins to all the dependencies of that job.